# Intersection of $n$ circles and $m$ lines

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Find the **maximum** number of points of intersection of $m$ straight lines and $n$ circles.

This is a high school level counting problem and it has been answered on MSE before as I could find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241472/the-greatest-number-of-points-of-intersection-of-n-circles-and-m-straight-lines).

And the answer turns out to be \begin{align} 2\binom n2+\binom m2+2n\cdot m \end{align}

But, isn't it that the number of possible points $\leq \left ( 2\binom n2+\binom m2+2n\cdot m\right)$? How do we know that such a configuration exists for all $n$?

Comment: You switched $n$ and $m$. I think the existence can be proved by induction.

Comment: @drhab Arghhh, edited ;)

Comment: The possible points are less than specified number but the number of $\mathbf {\text {maximum}}$ points can be given by specified number.  In this case we don't consider concurrent lines or parallel lines or touching circles or a tangent line and a circle. And you can prove its existence using induction

Comment: @Manthanein Yes, but I can't really construct the figure. Can you show me please? Induction is okay, I guess, that gives the idea of construction as well.

Comment: You can try constructing figures for all permutations when m and vary from 0 to 3 or at most 5,  the further cases will be bit tough to construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take circles with centres $(r,0)$ passing respectively through the points $(-2^{-r}, 0)$. It is easy to see that any two of these intersect in two points. The right-hand extremity of the larger of two of these circles lies outside the smaller, and the left-hand extremity lies inside it.

Now take any collection of lines in general position. Shrink it so that all the intersections fit inside the smallest circle and to the right of the line $x= 1$. The intersections of the lines are in the interior of all the circles, and the lines must therefore all cut each circle in two points.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a rough question : Can this idea be used when we are trying to find the number of regions formed by $n$ circles and $m$ lines? Can't we generate a recursion for these? (For the case of "just lines" a recursion can be developed)

Comment: Hello, can you please answer this?

Comment: @Mathbg That is a different question - so try asking it as a question - comments are not really suitable